# Create dashboard on Firebase Database for various metrics

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-bigquery

I have `events` in firebase database table where each event has certain fields. One of the field is `event_type`. What I want to achieve is to be able to visualize in graphical form, how many events of each type comes daily?

How do I do something like that in firebase database?

Q1. Is it possible to directly do this in firebase?

Q2. Do I need to move data to some other datasource (like Big query) and setup dashboard there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely possible to create a dashboard with aggregate data directly on the Firebase Realtime Database. But you'll have to take a different approach than with e.g. BigQuery.

With relational databases, you'll create a dashboard by running aggregation queries. For example to show how many events of each type, you'll run something like `SELECT type, COUNT(*) FROM events GROUP BY type`.

The Firebase Realtime Database (and most NoSQL databases) don't have such a `GROUP BY` operation, not a `COUNT()` method. So that means that you'd have to load all data into your dashboard, and group/count it there, which is quite expensive. That why on NoSQL databases you'll typically keep a running count for each type in the database and update that on every write operation. While this puts an overhead on each write operation, the dashboard itself suddenly becomes very simply when you do this. For an example of a simple counter, see the [function-samples repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/child-count).

This approach only works if you know up front what counters (and other aggregates) you want to show in the dashboard. If that isn't the case, many developers use the nightly backups from the Realtime Database to ingest the data into another system that lends itself more to exploratory querying, such as BigQuery.

Either approach can work fine. The right approach is a matter of your exact use-case (e.g. do you know the exact data you want in the dashboard, or are you still figuring that out?) and what you're most comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks Frank.  I know the exact data. I enabled backups of firebase database (which moves data to BigQuery). It created a json.gz file in a google storage. Is it possible to use these nightly backups to create a dashboard (using BigQuery may be?)

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Give it a spin, and if you get stuck post a question with what you tried and what went wrong.